# Windows 7 share drive is mounted and can cd into it from ubuntu but cannot ls,cp,mkdir,etc

Tags: windows, ubuntu-10.04, mount, network-shares

The title pretty much says it all, for example:

> myth:/media/saga_c/2005> pwd
>   /media/saga_c/2005
>   myth:/media/saga_c/2005> ls
>   ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied
>   myth:/media/saga_c/2005> cd 2005_05_08
>   myth:/media/saga_c/2005/2005_05_08> pwd
>   /media/saga_c/2005/2005_05_08
>   myth:/media/saga_c/2005/2005_05_08> ls
>
> ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied

I am thinking it is probably a permissions issue but maybe I am missing something more fundamental here. Am I not able to work with a windows shared folders from Ubutnu (ver 10.04)?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it sounds like a permission problem.

I hadn't mounted a Windows share in a while, but there seems to be two patterns I see on the internet. [[First]](http://industriousone.com/blog/mounting-windows-shares-linux) [[Second]](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/access-windows-shares-from-linux/)  I can't recall which I've used, they both look familiar.

Hopefully one of these will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should be able to mount a Windows (CIFS) share on modern Linux distros just fine, so a permissions issue is quite likely.

You might try the following:

- Try specifying Windows username and password when mounting, like so:

  mount -t smbfs -o username=$username,password=$password //$win-box/$share   t/$name-of-mountpoint

Windows has its fair share of irks when it comes to authentication, especially when usernames on server and client are identical, but the passwords don't match. Ideally, there should be a user/password combination on the Windows server that matches the one on the intended client.

- Check for NTFS **and** network permissions on the Windows machine. Try setting both to "Everyone" and see if you can connect.